Kamailio SBC Record Route header first line is empty, only the second line contains the IP
Record Route header line 1 is empty for 180 Ringing and 200 OK messages, the second line of the Record Route contains the IP. For the INVITE is not the case, both lines contain the IPs.
This causes the issue that the ACK to the 200 OK is not being forwarded to the correct IP.
What can cause this issue? The Record Route to be added but empty? Below I am adding some information regarding my setup.
The Kamailio has two interfaces, on the right side(eth1) is connected to an Asterisk and on hte left side is (eth0). The Asterisk is sending the ACK for the 200 ok but to the IP in the second line of the Record Route headerm which is the other interface(eth0).
Kamailio SBC interfaces
Empty Record Route Header
180 Ringing
200 OK
Any kind of support is appreciated.
Thanks!
This is the Record Route Configuration :

  `remove_hf("Route");
        if (is_request()) {
                if (is_method("INVITE")) {
                        #!ifndef RECORD_ROUTE_WORKAROUND
                        $var(loglevel)=2;
                        $var(logmessage)="Insert Record Route into " + $rm ;
                        route(LOGGING);

                        record_route();
                        #!endif

                        #!ifdef RECORD_ROUTE_WORKAROUND
                        if(ds_is_from_list(2, "3")) {
                                $var(loglevel)=2;
                                $var(logmessage)="Insert Record Route into " + $rm ;
                                route(LOGGING);
                                record_route();
                        }
                        if(ds_is_from_list(1, "3")) {
                                $var(loglevel)=2;
                                $var(logmessage)="Removing Record Route " + $rm ;
                                route(LOGGING);
                                remove_hf("Record-Route");
                        }
                        #!endif
                }
                /* Set request URI and TO header to the target server */
                if (ds_is_from_list(-1, "3")) {
                        if(is_method("INVITE")) {
                                if($ru!=$null) {
                                        $ru = "sip:" + $rU + "@" + $(avp(dsattrs){param.value,fqdn}) + ";user=phone" ;
                                }
                                if(is_present_hf("To")) {
                                        $td = $(avp(dsattrs){param.value,fqdn});
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        #!ifdef RECORD_ROUTE_WORKAROUND
        if (is_reply()) {
                if(ds_is_from_list(2, "3")) {
                        $var(loglevel)=2;
                        $var(logmessage)="Instert Record Route into " + $rm ;
                        route(LOGGING);
                        record_route();
                }
                if(ds_is_from_list(1, "3")) {
                        $var(loglevel)=2;
                        $var(logmessage)="Removing Record Route " + $rm ;
                        route(LOGGING);
                        remove_hf("Record-Route");
                }
        }
        #!endif
}`



Record-Route headers are added only in the SIP INVITE requests, the corresponding SIP replies must only mirror them. If the outgoing INVITE has correct Record-Route values, but the corresponding incoming 18x/200 replies come with and empty Record-Route, then very likely the problem is at the UA that generates the reply, try to investigate there.
Regarding the kamailio.cfg snippet in the description, it should be no removal of Record-Route header for reply, there is a remove_hf("Record-Route") in the if (is_reply()) { } block. It is guarded by an #!ifdef, maybe it is not active.
As a side note, if the outgoing INVITE from Kamailio is with the first Record-Route empty, that is usually because record_route() is executed before msg_apply_changes().
